# Use !important Keyword In Sass Maps

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm using a sass mixin library called typi  (https://github.com/zellwk/typi), and now how can i make use of !important keyword in sass map functions, here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
$i:!important;
$heading:(
null:( 80px,80px $i),
large:(60px,60px $i),
small:(40px,40px $i)
);
```

I'm trying to use !important keyword within key value such as
null:( 80px $i,80px $i)

whenever I use the keyword, I get this error on compiling

" error sass/style.scss (Line 30 of sass/typi/scss/ty/_functions.scss: $number: "80px!important" is not a number for `unitless') "

Comment: if you use proper specificity you shouldn't need an !important

Comment: i agree, though there are situations when you've to use !important too :)

Comment: You cant pass `!important` to function. Because it expects just a number, not a css property value.

Answer (score 0):

As a mapping , you need to add the `!important` inside the call, not on the map, so it would look like:

```
@include typi($heading, !important);
```

This is not a good practice, but sometimes when you are working with the inheritance on SASS, you need it. And the correct syntax is this one.

Hope that will help :)